# Estimate probability using forward Kolmogorov equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Given two machines, both of which have an exponential lifetime with mean $\frac{1}{2}$. There is a single repairman that can service machines at an exponential rate $1$. Assuming that the system starts in a state in which both machines are working, using a numerical method, estimate the probability that both machines are working at time 1 using forward Kolmogorov equations.

**My attempt:** Let $X(t) =$ # of machines that failed by time $t$. So we have 3 states: $0$, $1$ and $2$ machines failed. Order the states as $0$, $1$ and $2$, then the rate transition matrix Q is:
$$Q =\pmatrix{-4 & 4 &  0\\ 1 & -3 & 2\\ 0 &  1 & -1}$$

Now, using the forward Kolmogorov equation, we would get one of the $9$ equations is:

$P'_{00}(t) = -4P_{00}(t) + P_{01}(t)$

Thus, we only need to estimate $P_{00}(1)$ from numerically solving the differential equation above. Using Euler's method with stepsize $h=1$, since the system is currently in state $0$, we have: $P_{00}(0) = 1$ and  $P_{01}(0) = 0$. Thus, by Euler's method, $P_{00}(1)\approx  P_{00}(0) + h(-4P_{00}(0) + P_{01}(0)) = 1 + 1(-4+0) = -3 < 0$.

**My question:** Why did I get the negative probability? Is it because the stepsize $h=1$ is too large? But if I set $h<1$, why does it work? I don't see the difference except the increase in the accuracy of our estimated probability.

Comment: I don't understand, why would there be 9 equations? There are three states, so a distribution on the states is given by three nonnegative numbers. (Two, technically, because of normalization, but whatever.) So what you actually meant is $P_0=-4P_0'+P_1$. But yes, Euler's method can give horrible nonsense results when the step size is too large.

Comment: In particular you generally need $h $ to be less than the reciprocal of the magnitude of the largest eigenvalues to have stability. So consider h smaller than 1/4 to be sure of sane results.

Comment: Well the forward Kolmogorov equation is: $P'_{ij}(t) = \sum_{k} P_{ik}(t)q_{kj}$ where $q_{jj} = -v_{j}$? So we have 3 states, and $i,j$ each could be $0,1,2$. How many equations you had for this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help. But if $h<\frac{1}{4}$, I would need to solve for 9 equations, which is crazy:P

Comment: That's not what it says. You have $P'=Q^TP $, in column vector form. In components that reads $P_i'=\sum_j P_j q_{ji}$. That makes 3 equations in your case.

Comment: I also don't see why you're doing your numerical method by hand rather than with software. In particular, if you take $h<1/4$ you will get a positive probability, but that doesn't necessarily mean it will be accurate until $h$ is a fair bit smaller still.

Comment: @Ian: that equation is not wrong. It was printed in many probability books (please see Ross's Intro to probability book).Your $P'_i$ does not show from which state we go into state $i$, thus we don't know the transition probability even after solving to get $P_i(t)$. I could see why you only have 3 equations due to that lack of the previous states in your formula.

Comment: @Ian: I could use the software but I don't know which one has the package for solving system of ODE. Maybe I woukd check Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: You're totally wrong here. The formula I gave does take into account how likely you are to be in another state $j$ (this is the effect of $P_j$) and how fast you leave the state $j$ to go to $i$ (this is the effect of $q_{ji}$).

Comment: Anyway, there are plenty of ways to solve this numerically. (It can actually be solved analytically too, but the problem says not to do that, and the result is pretty ugly anyway.) What exactly I would suggest depends on the context the problem came from. They might want you to just use a premade method like ode45 or they might want you to write your own little script. But I totally doubt they expect you to do 8+ Euler steps.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing on having to write my own script to solve it. But 3 equations are far better than 9. Still not sure why I am wrong though.

Comment: Basically I don't see why you're looking for $P_{ij}$ in the first place, or even what that represents. $P_i(t)$ is the probability to find yourself in state $i$ at time $t$. Is your $P_{ij}(t)$ supposed to be the probability that you are currently in $i$ and your next transition will be to $j$, or something? You don't need that here, you just need the probability to be in state $0$ at time $1$ given that you are in state $0$ at time $0$. This is the first component of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} e^Q$.

Comment: @Ian: could you give some thoughts on this problem as well? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983993/birth-death-process-with-single-server

Comment: @Ian: oh because I want to find $P_{00}(1)$. But your suggested thought hints me to approximate $e^Q$ by $I+Q+Q^2/2!$, which hopefully gives me the first element $P_{00}(1) < 1$. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh, now I see what you meant by $P_{ij} $, you meant the probability to be in j if you originally started from i. But you do not need all 9 $P_{ij} $ here, the only relevant ones are $P_{0j} $. Anyway yes that means that your matrix $P (t)$ is just $e^{Qt} $.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The only relevant one is actually $P_{00}$. So you agree that I could approximate $P_{00}(1)$ by the first element of $I+Q+\frac{Q^2}{2!}$?

Comment: Technically yes but it will be a bad approximation. You'll need more terms than that to get a decent estimate, because of the relatively high rates.

Comment: @Ian: I agree, but I just hope it would be below $1$. Unless I could do that expansion by some softwares:)

Comment: I doubt it will even be between $0$ and $1$ with just that many terms. But yes, you could approximate $e^Q$ using software if you wanted. (Also I think the matrix is actually $e^{Q^T t}$, not $e^{Qt}$.)

Comment: @Ian: the convergence I got is after the 18th term, and the result is approximately $0.1173$. May I know what was your result?

Comment: (6*exp(3^(1/2) - 4))/13 + (6*exp(- 3^(1/2) - 4))/13 + (2*3^(1/2)*exp(- 3^(1/2) - 4))/39 - (2*3^(1/2)*exp(3^(1/2) - 4))/39 + 1/13 is the exact answer from Matlab with the first four digits indeed being 0.1173. (That said, I doubt this is what your assignment wanted; I expect they wanted something more like ode45).

Comment: That's quite a significant feat! How did you code that up in Matlab Sir?

Comment: Define A normally; then expm(sym(A)), read off the (1,1) entry. It only works out nicely because the example is small, though.

Comment: Note though that the $A$ I was using is the transpose of your transition probability matrix.

Comment: @Ian: thanks a ton for your details. I tried yours successfully (did not know of the function "expm" in Matlab till today:p). 

By the way, could you help verify if the last row of my rate transition matrix in this problem is correct? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980867/expected-time-for-a-system-to-reach-the-failure-state/1980907#1980907. I'm a bit skeptical due to the ugly result I got for the limiting probabilities.

Comment: I think you forgot that the engines are repaired one at a time, so the repair rate is no faster when two are down than when one is down. But that does not change the stationary distribution in this case.

Comment: @Ian: I thought about it too, but wasn't sure:( So the last row should be $0, 1, -1$?. This means it does change the limiting probabilities.

Comment: Oh, yes, so it does, because distributions are applied on the left not the right. You're correct.

Comment: @Ian: my bad for this follow up email. But for that question, since that is the CTMC, I would need to solve $PQ=0$ rather than $\pi P=\pi$ if I want to find the fraction of time the system is in a particular state?

Comment: For the long term probabilities that is correct. Your question was not about those, however.

Comment: what do you mean by "my question is not about those?"

Comment: Your question in the OP is about finite time probabilities not long run probabilities.